# How to create black cold lava rock material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders, workflow

I need to create this lava rock material with small cavities, but I can't find any similar texture.

I tried adding some Voronoi textures mixed with *Color Ramps* to create the normal/displacement map for the wholes but it doesn't look good.

Could you give me an idea on how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Displacement in cycles with the material settings changed from the default of “bump only” to “displacement only” for displacement maps. Normal maps are faked, so that will not look good. An alternate solution might be to make a particle system of small globby air bubbles, and then use a bully and modifier to cut holes in the stone. This would actually be more accurate.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard did you try to dictate boolean lol

Comment: @AllenSimpson got me, lol

Comment: This kind of rock is called [Scoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoria) (as opposed to pumice, which is usually lighter in color).

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using *Voronoi Textures*, use *Noise Textures* (more randomly shaped) of several different scales, clamped with ColorRamps  to make the dimples of different sizes. Mix that with a sort of neutral grey to "soften it" slightly.  Mix the end result very slightly with another Noise Texture to make the whole surface bumpy like rock.
Use the mix as a basis for displacement, and adjust the scales and ColorRamp sliders until it looks like what you need:

[image: Material1]

Comment: I really love your answers and you have a great fundamental understanding of Blender and i learnt a lot from you.....but this yellow text color on that green background makes my eyes bleed.... ;) :D +1 anyway.... just another great answer

Comment: yes you can guess it's a Christopher Bennett's answer right away by the UI colors ^^

Comment: no guess...that's for sure! ;) it is his BRAND! :D

Comment: Wow! That's incredible, thank you very much! :))

Comment: @Chris/moonboots - Lol. The lemon-lime a bit too much? Hey, when my Blender wants Sprite, I give it Sprite ;)

Comment: 